# Can the nmea drivers be used with kinetic?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to run the `nmea_navsat_driver` project on Kinetic (on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), I get the following error:

```
$ rosrun nmea_navsat_driver nmea_serial_driver _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 _baud:=4800
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/feitew/catkin_ws/src/nmea_navsat_driver/scripts/nmea_serial_driver", line 39, in <module>
    import libnmea_navsat_driver.driver

ImportError: No module named libnmea_navsat_driver.driver
```

Is there any change I can make to fix this, or do I have to switch to Indigo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249490/can-the-nmea-drivers-be-used-with-kinetic?/) by [feitew](https://answers.ros.org/users/28737/feitew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-07**:
Can you tell us how you installed the package? How did you setup your workspace, etc?

**Comment by [feitew](https://answers.ros.org/users/28737/feitew/) on 2016-12-09**:
I installed ROS with

sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full

Basically, I just followed all of the instructions here:
http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-09**:
And how did you add `nmea_navsat_driver` to your workspace? Did you only clone the repository? Then what?

**Comment by [feitew](https://answers.ros.org/users/28737/feitew/) on 2016-12-09**:
I cloned it from https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver into the src folder of my catkin workspace, then ran catkin make.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-10**:
Two things:

- you might want to run a `rosdep install --from-paths ~/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src`, then run `catkin_make` again
- did you also do a `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` after `catkin_make` was finished?

**Comment by [feitew](https://answers.ros.org/users/28737/feitew/) on 2016-12-11**:
Thanks! That fixed part of the problem. The command runs now, but it's telling me I don't have permission to access the usb port with my gps. It works fine with picocom, but with the command above, I get

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> ImportError: No module named libnmea_navsat_driver.driver
> ```

You either haven't installed all of the prerequisites of the package, or you've forgotten to `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` after `catkin_make` was finished.

Would still be nice if you could tell us how you setup your workspace: without `source`ing `setup.bash`, `rosrun` should not have been able to find the `nmea_navsat_driver` package. So I'm curious as to what you did.

> The command runs now, but it's telling me I don't have permission to access the usb port with my gps. It works fine with picocom, but with the command above, I get

> ```
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
> ```

That sounds like a different problem, so it would be best if you open a new question for that. Make sure to search first, as permission problems with (serial) ports are a common topic.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0